# Replace before and after text

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to replace but leave between characters unchanged:

Example:

```
<column name="propertys_uid">30</column>
<column name="property_name">Villa</column>
<column name="property_street">5th street</column>
<column name="property_town">New York</column>
```

should become

```
<yourreference>30</yourreference>
<name>Villa</name>
<street>5th street</street>
<town>New York</town>
```

As you can see the content between `> ... <` should not be changed. A normal find and replace will not work as the 
`</column>` always needs to be different. I think I got the first step to find using `<column name="propertys_uid">.*?</column>` but its not working at the replace with `<yourreference>*?</yourreference> –`

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups in your replace. So, for instance:

Find: `<column name="propertys_uid">([^<]+)</column>`

Replace: `<yourreference>$1</yourreference>`

This would give `<yourreference>30</yourreference>` in your example

If the name of the original tag plays into the desired replacement, you can do that too:

Find: `<column name="property_([^"]+)">([^<]+)</column>`

Replace: `<$1>$2</$1>`

This would give `<name>Villa</name>` in your example

Answer (score 0):

You could record a macro and go through each Replace step by step.

Start recording your macro, then:

- Press `CTRL H`
- Select 'Regular Expression' for `Search Mode`

**REPEAT BELOW STEPS FOR EACH ELEMENT**

- Add your Regex in `Find What` field, eg `<column name="propertys_uid">(.*?)</column>`
- Add Replacement in `Replace With` field with `<yourreference>$1</yourreference>`
- Click Replace All button

After you have done that for each element stop recording the macro and save it.

To find the macro on windows 7/8 go to `C:\Users\{{USERNAME}}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`. You must shutdown notepad++ for the macro to be saved to the xml file.

It's a bit convoluted doing like this but will work and saves on brain power! phew

Answer (score 0):

I see notepad++ tag there, you can use group regex in notepad++.

just modify your regex for a bit like this `<column name="propertys_uid">(.*)<\/column>` and replace with `<yourreference>\1</yourreference>` make sure your search mode is in "Regular Expression".

and you will get someting like `<yourreference>30</yourreference>` from `<column name="propertys_uid">30</column>`